# jslint + node --harmony

Tags: node.js, jslint, ecmascript-harmony

How do I get `jslint` to play nice with `node --harmony`? When I run node with the harmony flag, I get `jslint` errors like this:

```
 #1 Expected an identifier and instead saw 'let'.
```

To summarize I want jslint to recognize that I'm using ES6 extensions. Is there a way?

Comment: Dude, seriously? do you even know what I'm asking? --harmony is the node extensions for experimental es6 features. So my use of let is a block scope variable declaration, not a variable name.

Comment: Have you tried `node --use-strict --harmony`?

Comment: Yes that allows node to run but it doesn't prevent jslint from complaining, which is what I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSLint does not currently have any support for any of the specced or proposed ES6 features. JSHint does have a basic level of support for some ES6 features, and is gaining more support fairly regularly:

- Destructuring
- Rest parameters/spread operator
- Generator functions
- Block scoping (including constants and `let`)
- Classes
- The `for-of` loop
- Modules

Note that you will have to activate this behaviour in JSHint, by setting the [`esnext`](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esnext) option to `true`.